# remove link and a portion of text

Tags: jquery

How can i remove a portion of this below

```
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com">ICS File Export</a></h3>
```

Result would be this

```
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display: This Month | <a href="//mysite1.com">ICS File Export</a></h3>
```

Need this portion removed

```
| <a href="//mysite.com">Full Season</a>
```

The URL path for the links are always changing , so am unable to use url strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the 5'000'000 options is to use split to get an array and then concatenate the array values back together skipping the middle value `[1]`

```js
var element = document.querySelector('h3');
var stringArray = element.innerHTML.split('|');
// stringArray looks now like:
// [
//    "<h3 class=\"h3-menu\">Display: This Month ",
//    " <a href=\"//mysite.com\">Full Season</a> ",
//    " <a href=\"//mysite1.com\">ICS File Export</a></h3>"
// ]

element.innerHTML = stringArray[0] + '|' + stringArray[2];
```

```html
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com">ICS File Export</a></h3>
```

Comment: ok , the link urls are always changing , so i have to attack this by using the text for the link "Full Season"

Comment: The URLs can change as much as they want. All it needs is the two `|` then it works. If the two `|` are not there it doesn't work

Comment: ok i'm trying it on site and will not work , set up jsfiddle and will not work  https://jsfiddle.net/26oygxua/4/

Comment: @MShack aaah well you don't do anything in the fiddle with the value.. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/uem426sf/ (also updated the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fiddle demonstrating @Caramba's solution:

```js
var h3=document.querySelector('h3'), 
arr=h3.innerHTML.split('|');
arr.splice(1,1);
h3.innerHTML=arr.join('|');
```

```html
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com">ICS File Export</a></h3>
```

I didn't use jQuery, as it is not really needed here.

Should there be several places where you need to do this operation then you can do it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click',function(){
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h3')).forEach(
  function(h3){
   var arr=h3.innerHTML.split('|');
   arr.splice(1,1);
   h3.innerHTML=arr.join('|');
 });
});
```

```html
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display 1: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com?itm=1">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com?itm=1">ICS File Export</a></h3>
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display 2: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com?itm=2">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com?itm=2">ICS File Export</a></h3>
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display 3: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com?itm=3">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com?itm=3">ICS File Export</a></h3>
<h3 class="h3-menu">Display 4: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com?itm=4">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com?itm=4">ICS File Export</a></h3>
<button id="go">click me to cut off the unwanted portions above</button>
```

To visualise the "before and after" effect I added a button at the bottom. incidentally, if you click it again, another part of your links would be removed. To prevent that from happening you could add an option to your `addEventListener()` call:

```
document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click',function(){
  // function code, as above ...
}, { once: true });  // this will de-activate the listener after the first click
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
var url = $('a:contains("Full Season")');
url.remove();

var h3Text = $('h3:contains(" | ")').html();

$('.h3-menu').html(h3Text.replace('|  ', ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="h3-menu">Display: This Month | <a href="//mysite.com">Full Season</a> | <a href="//mysite1.com">ICS File Export</a></h3>
```